# Java, Stream, Collectors, Functional programming : How to make a double entry map?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I'm trying to understand streams and maps.

I have a Stream of "horse" object. Each "horse" has a "breed", and a "favorite food".

What i'm trying to do is to create a thing (probably a map) looking like a double entry array, with the breeds into the rows, and the favorite foods into the columns.

At the intersection of rows and columns, I would to have the count of horses.

To have horses grouped by breeds, I have to do this :

```java
    Map<Breed, List<Horse>> map = horsesStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(h -> h.breed));
```

To have horses grouped by favorite food, almost the same thing :

```java
    Map<FavoriteFood, List<Horse>> map = horsesStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(h -> h.favoriteFood));
```

And to have the count grouped by food, I do this :

```java
    Map<Food, Long> map = horsesStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy((h-> h.favoriteFood), Collectors.counting());
```

how can I combine all three?

I tried :

```java
    Map<Breed, Map<Food, List<Horse>>> map= 
    horsesStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy((h -> h.breed), Collectors.groupingBy(h-> h.favoriteFood)));
```

But now, I don't know what to do at all.

Can you help me ? Maybe some clues ?

### The right answer was :

```
     Map<Breed, Map<Food, Long>> map = horsesStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy((c -> c.breed),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c.favoriteFood, Collectors.counting())));
```

**Thanks you, Sweeper**

Comment: If you just want a `Map<Breed, Map<Food, List<Horse>>>`, the code you tried already gives you that, so what do you want exactly? What do you mean by "combine all three"?

Comment: Do you mean `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.breed, Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.favouriteFood, Collectors.counting())));`?

Comment: It makes no sense what you expect. Forget streams. When group by food, it will include horses of *different* breeds. So do you expect food mapped to breed? It is nonsense.

Comment: Well, you should answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution :

The solution was :

```java
    public static Map<Breed, Map<Food, Long>> breedFoodCount (List<Horse> horses){
            // Get a stream
            Stream<Horse> horsesStream = horses.stream();
            return horsesStream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy((c -> c.breed),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c.favoriteFood, Collectors.counting())));
        }
```